# How can I make an affine transformation to a grayscale image and plot the result

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am trying to process an affine transformation to a grayscale image (to be more exact, that is a txt file, I can read it as a 1030*781 matrix, and the value in each cell is the grayscale value)
I have estimated the 6 parameters (i.e. a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) using control points. So I can transform every point in the original file (row, column) into new XY-system (X,Y)

and how can I plot the result as another grayscale image?

So for now... my progress is that I can get a series of points with (X,Y,Z), XY is the coordinates after affine transformation, and Z is the grayscale value, corresponding to that of its 'original' point.

And how can I plot these 1030*731 points as a grayscale image?

(I am new to stackoverflow so I still not find where to attch my files, I will try attach them later if I find :( )

I am using MATLAB R2020a btw.

[a screenshot of my txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGihc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You cannot attach files on Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] to see how SO works. What we'd need from you is a [mre], i.e. a *small* sample of your data (e.g. a `rand(10,10)` matrix, don't upload that full one please) and the code you have thus far.